# Changing the background color of datagridview from initialization

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a problem in changing the background color of my datagridview from initialization
It doesn't changed at all..

I have a different kind of Status\es: NEW, OPEN, COMPLETED and DELAYED\PENDING
And there is condition if the color will be changed.

if the status is COMPLETED, the background color of that row will turn to color RED,
if NEW and OPEN, the color will be GREEN,
and if DELAYED\PENDING, the color will be GRAY.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    econ = new SqlConnection();
    econ.ConnectionString = emp_con;
    econ.Open();


    ecmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Det_Stat FROM DETAILS", econ);
    ecmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    ecmd.Connection = econ;
    dr = ecmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        string det_stat = Convert.ToString(dr["Det_Stat"]);
        if (det_stat == "COMPLETED")
        {                        
            this.dgvStatusComment.DefaultCellStyle = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    MessageBox.Show(x.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Connection Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

I know I forget something or I do really don't know how to do it. but i tried many times. I did my best to work it but it seems no success. please help me. this will finished my project.

Thank you and God bless.

Comment: Where are you assigning other colors? Are you missing that :)

Comment: @Amar Palsapure, yeah your right. I forgot to include it. but they are the same in my if statement.

Comment: I changed the code in my if statement: 
this.dgvStatusComment.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; But still no success.

Answer (score 1):

From what I got from your question, you will need to iterate on the rows of your `DataGridView` and according to status assign the backcolor to the individual row. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29489/Use-an-Event-to-Set-the-Row-Cell-BackColor-in-a-Cu) article, it might help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I found a solution. I will post my answer later. Thanks again.